# Simple way to declare all parent constructors?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I would like to know if there is a VS tool to simply generate all parent constructors in child.

My problem is that when I inherit from any class and want to be able to use all the constructors defined in the parent I have to write a lot of code.

When I for example define this class: `class MyList<T> : List<T>{}`
It is not surprising that only way to create MyList object is to call `new MyList<>()`. If I want to be able to use all of the constructors of `List<T>` I would need to manually write a lot of constructors (well not in the `List<T>` case since he has just 3 constructors..) like for example this:

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    internal MyList(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
}
```

And my question is whether there is a tool in Visual Studio (and which tool in case) that would generate these constructors on my behalf.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it but it seem Resharper has that functionality according to their website http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html

Comment: Yes, it has this functionality and it is an intersting tool, unfortunately (for me) it is for free only for 30 days.

Comment: I wonder why you made the constructor `internal` in your `MyList<T>` example. In the base class, the similar constructor is `public`, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be No. Visual Studio does not come with a tool for that.

According to comment by WannaCSharp, ReSharper can do this.